# Shorten plain div text

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, trim

I am using a service called 'embedly' which is showing my feeds. I'm trying to shorten the text of this feed, so I tried:

```
$('.description').html(
     function(){
         return $.trim($(this).html())
                .substring(0, 100)
                .split(" ").slice(0, -1)
                .join(" ") + "...";}
);
```

I placed this in document ready and also in 'window.load' but nothing seems to work. Here is an example: [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/2VBSX/1/)

Comment: I've updatet my answer with sample code, didn't have time to test it yet but I believe it's correct, will have a look ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one took me a very long time to figure out, but I think the best you can do is give the elements a second to load into the DOM, and then run your function: http://jsfiddle.net/2VBSX/5/

```
$('div.newscontainer').embedly({
    key:':e0a98aba95ef11e09dcd4040d3dc5c07'
}).hide();

setTimeout(function() {
    $('div.newscontainer').show().find('.description').html(
        function(){
            return $.trim($(this).html())
            .substring(0, 100)
            .split(" ").slice(0, -1)
            .join(" ") + "...";
        }
    );
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort and answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Jquery's HTML doesn't accept a function as argument, but only plain HTML (a string).
To do what you wanto to do, use `.each()` :)

**Correction:** as pointed out by the commenter below, my code is correct but .html() **does** indeed accept a function as argument, in the form `$(...).html(function(index, oldhtml));`, making possible to access directly the html part. (Thanks to @Raminson for pointing it out)

Prior to @Raminson's observation my code was:

```
$('.description').each(
     function(i,e){
         $(e).html(reduce($(e).html()));}
);

function reduce(s)
{
         return s.substring(0, 100)
                .split(" ").slice(0, -1)
                .join(" ") + "...";
}
```

With the correction, the first part becomes (still using the `reduce()` function):

```
$(".description").html(function(i,s) { return reduce(s); });
```

Comment: @Youss there was a missing parentheses, anyway read Raminson's correction and my updated answer.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the 'loading process' of embedly and feedburner..??

Comment: I know how to shorten text, the problem is shorting the text with feedburner and embedly..

Comment: It depends, @Youss, does feedburner (which I don't know) load the feeds with AJAX/Javascript or are the feeds already present in the page (generated server-side)?

Comment: Nothing is server-side, its all ajax/javascript Except for embedly which sometimes uses cache for img (but that is not my server)

Comment: @Youss Then your code won't work anyway. `$(document).ready()` works only for elements *already* in the page but not newly created ones. You should delegate the shortening function with the `$('element').on(event, selector, function)` syntax

Comment: @Youss because the content isn't being inserted at the time that the window is loaded. `window.onload` and `document.ready` don't account for data that's in the process of being fetched from another server. The Feedburner data is being fetched and then inserted into the DOM after the scripts for it have been loaded and run, and the data returned from the external site. See my answer to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

So, my other answer is not valid because the OP didn't mention that all the elements were created on the fly, so they cannot be matched in the classical way.

If the modifications are attached to a suitable event (click, for example), then it would be easy to use delegates with `.on()`, as they are valid also for new elements inserted in the DOM.
But alas this is not the case, we must operate on the element's creation.

One solution would be @ChrisClower's one (a timer polling the page regularly for new elements).

Another solution would be to use the LiveQuery plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

Then all would be simple:

```
$(".description").livequery(function() {  $(e).html(reduce($(e).html())); });

 function reduce(s)
{
     return s.substring(0, 100)
            .split(" ").slice(0, -1)
            .join(" ") + "..."; 
}
```

Comment: @Youss have you installed the plugin?

Comment: Thanks but I was being stupid...the embedly api already has a built in words/chars parameter http://embed.ly/docs/arguments